# Plotting in R with a color scale

Tags: r, plot, colors

I have a file 4 columns and I would like to plot first vs second column and color it based on the 3rd column with a color scale. I tried scatter plot but don't know how to get the color scale on the side. I'm looking for something like a surface look.

Comment: Depends on the plotting paradigm, but the right search term is "legend".

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure of what you mean by surface look.
Following is a basic sample which might help -

```
a <- sample(1:20, 5)
b <- sample(1:20, 5)
x <- c('A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B')
df <- data.frame(a, b, x)
df

#    a   b   x
#1   8  14   A
#2  16   2   A
#3  17  11   A
#4   9   7   B
#5   6   3   B

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = a, y = b, color = x) + geom_point(size = 5)
```

[image: output]

You can also manually edit colors and legend sizes and more with additional parameters.